# SVG height is undefined in Vue + Quasar testing using Jest

Tags: unit-testing, svg, vuejs2, quasar-framework, quasar

I receive `SVG` as a String from API. `SVG` has XML header and I parse `svg` element from the String as follows:

```
const svgXml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(svg, 'image/svg+xml')
const svg = svgXml.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]
```

I need the height of `svg` and I am doing it as follows. While running the application, there are no errors and height is retrieved correctly.

```
svg.height.baseVal.value
```

I am mocking the API response in unit tests. It is exactly the same API response, which works correctly during the normal application run. While running the unit tests, I get the following error.

```
Cannot read property 'baseVal' of undefined
```

`console.log` for `svg` shows that their is `height` attribute.

```
<svg width="942.0" height="961.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

I cannot find the reason why `svg.height` is undefined in testing.
I am doing Vue/Quasar testing via Jest using following libraries

```
@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing-unit-jest
@vue/test-utils
```